# How to handle downloading files in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have an array, that contains URL addresses to remote files.

By default I tried to download all files using this bad approach:

```
for a in ARRAY:
   wget.download(url=A, out=path_folder)
```

So, it falls by the some reason: host server return timeout, some URL are broken etc.

How to handle this process more professional? But I can not apply this to my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you have a way to define a timeout, it reads the filename from the url and retrieves big files as stream, so your memory won't get overfilled

```
import requests
import urlparse, os
timeout = 30  # Seconds
for url in urls:
    try:
        # Make the actual request, set the timeout for no data to X seconds and enable streaming responses so we don't have to keep the large files in memory
        request = requests.get(url, timeout=timeout, stream=True)
        # Get the Filename from the URL
        name = os.path.basename(urlparse.urlparse(url).path)
        # Open the output file and make sure we write in binary mode
        with open(name, 'wb') as fh:
            # Walk through the request response in chunks of 1024 * 1024 bytes, so 1MiB
            for chunk in request.iter_content(1024 * 1024):
                # Write the chunk to the file
                fh.write(chunk)
    except Exception as e:
        print("Something went wrong:", e)
```

Answer (score 3):

If you still want to use `wget`, you can wrap the download in a `try..except` block that just prints any exception and moves on to the next file:

```
for f in files:
    try:
        wget.download(url=f, out=path_folder)
    except Exception as e:
        print("Could not download file {}".format(f)
        print(e)
```

Comment: Yes, I did this, but how to solve timeout? And how to control process by time?

Comment: @Amely Well, if you did this, why did you not show that you did this? And what do you mean with "control process by time"?

Comment: Main problem is server timeout. So process executes so long when it handles over 100 files.

Comment: Which server does timeout? The server your script is running on, or the server your files are beeing downloaded from? Your server should be able to handle 100 file downloads, they are downloaded one by one and not all at the same time, also a python process can live a really long time without having a "timeout"

Comment: Yes, it is my server, I call python script from browser and after time I get timeout and 502 server error.

Comment: 502 is Bad Gateway, so your urls, you are trying to download from are not going anywhere

Comment: Do you mean I get 502 Bad Gateway because I try to load image that is not available?

Answer (score 0):

you can use urllib

```
import urllib.request
urllib.request.urlretrieve('http://www.example.com/files/file.ext', 'folder/file.ext')
```

you can use a `try: except:` around the retrive url, to catch any errors

```
try:
    urllib.request.urlretrieve('http://www.example.com/files/file.ext', 'folder/file.ext')
except Exception as e:
    print('The server couldn\'t fulfill the request.')
    print('Error code: ', e.code)
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding it as another answer,

If you want to solve the timeout you can use the requests library

```
import requests 
try:
   requests.get('http://url/to/file')
catch Exception as e:
   print('Error code: ', e.code)
```

**if you haven't specified any time it won't timeout**